# Onsubmit event is not null and JavaScript object says it's null?

Tags: javascript

A picture is worth a 1000 words:
[image]

As you can see from the picture above the form has a onsubmit event. But when I try to reference the onsubmit even it's telling me it's null.

The reason I'm asking this question is because I'm trying to clear the onsubmit event:

```
doc.getElementById("frmMaster").onsubmit = null;
```

Which is not working.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: EventListenerList is introduced in DOM 3 but no browser support it yet. https://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20010823/events.html#Events-EventListenerList

Comment: **1st.** I'm pretty sure, the `javascript:`-part in the onsubmit-attribute is wrong. Afaik there should be valid JS, and this isn't. **2nd.** changing the onsubmit-attribute also changes the onsubmit-property, but changing the property doesn't necessarily change the attribute as well. (afaik. Browser dependant) **3rd** The property is the one that matters! That's what is executed, no matter what the attribute says.

Comment: On your first point. Actually the "javascript:" part is put in there by asp.net.Its not something we actually added ourselves. Your 2nd point is how i actually was able was able to fix the issue yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work around the issue yesterday. After browsing the object hierarchy using chrome developer tools i noticed the object had a "onsubmit" attribute but the "onsubmit" property was already null. So:

```
doc.getElementById("frmMaster").removeAttribute("onsubmit");
```

successfully removed the event. I admit i don't totally grasp the difference between the event as a property or as an attribute but at least it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe to unregister events you must use `removeEventListener('event', boundFunction)`. A problem that arises from the code you have is that WebForm_OnSubmit may not be defined at a place accessible to you. What you will need to do is get that function into a context you can access from the console (or wherever you ultimately want to call this code). So you can essentially do this:

```
/* 
    somewhere in your server code, or wherever this WebForm_OnSubmit is defined
    var handleToWebForm_OnSubmit = WebForm_OnSubmit; //must be global scope
    // you will need to get a reference in javascript to this function 
    // and bind it so that you can willingly unbind it
*/
doc.getElementById("frmMaster").removeEventListener('submit', handleToWebForm_OnSubmit)
```